# Charge density of Conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

Surface charge density of a conductor at a particular region on its surface is inversely proportional to the radius of curvature at that region. But this is valid only when there is no electric field.

How will we calculate if electric field is also present? Please explain with any example.

Comment: When you say "no electric field" do you mean no **external** electric field or none at all?

Comment: Yes I mean "no external electric field"

Answer (score 0):

Your premise seems false. In classical electromagnetism, in zero field, surface charge density on a conductor is zero.

It is electric field that attracts charge to the surface, and this process quickly reaches equilibrium such that the external field is exactly negated by the field of the surface charges.

You are right that solving Poisson equation with given boundary conditions leads to high charge density on sharp edges, but this is just a mathematical exercise.

At any rate, electrostatic field inside a conductor is zero.

Comment: The conductor may be charged.

Comment: @my2cts any netto charge in the conductor would break the assumption of zero field.

Comment: I was taking about presence of external electric filed

Comment: Computing charge density for arbitrary conductive objects in arbitrary external field is hard and has to be done numerically. More details can be found here using e.g. the [Search] button.

Answer (score 0):

there are two sides to this question. the transient state and the steady state.
in the steady state, as we know, in a conductor, the electrical field is always zero. the reason is the charges are free to move. and they only stop when there is no force to move them. hence, they stop when their positioning negates any electrical field that was formerly induced in the conductor.
for the transient state though, things are a little different. until everything is settled and we reach the steady state, we still have field and so we still have force. force means movement. and we "just" have to solve the physical equation on charges. well, that "just" is a bit difficult. but not too difficult. you can find the needed variables and equations in physic courses and books.