# Surface charge density of a conductor is inversely proportional to radius of curvature: proof?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I have heard the statement
"The surface charge density at a point on a conductor is inversely proportional to the radius of curvature at that point"

For example in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585585/383029) stackexchange post.

Is there an explanation for this?
I understand computing the potential/charge of an arbitrary shape is compicated, is done using Poisson's equation, and is done numerically.
Hence I wouldn't mind a "handwavy" or less rigorous explanation.

We are of course working under the assumptions of ideal conductors: zero field inside, charge accumulates on surface.

A practical example I have read about, is that lightning rods have sharp, pointy ends, which increases up charge density from the ground, and sets up an "electric wind" with an atmospheric cloud.

I am following Griffiths. I thought of using this formula: $\sigma = - \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}$ but I got stuck at comparing $ \frac{\partial V}{\partial n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge density isn't proportional to curvature in a charged conductor where the curvature varies. Take a thin cylindrical needle perhaps with spherical ends as an example.

Charge will flow until the electric field is normal to the surface everywhere. Suppose the charge was uniformly distributed. A charge near the end would feel forces from a few charges on one side and many on the other. It would be pushed toward the end. Charge builds up near the end until the excess charge balances the forces.

The curvature of the needle is constant over the surface, except at the end caps. But the charge distribution is not.

Comment: Excellent point mmesser314. In general charge density is not related to conductor geometry.  However, folks should be sure to see Farcher's post for cases when charge density can be dependent on conductor geometry.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus - A quibble. Charge density is determined by conductor geometry. The distribution isn't always $\sigma \propto 1/r$.

Comment: Of course it depends on geometry in the sense of charge divided by total area. I agree with you in that the charge density is just uniform, i.e. doesn't vary over the surface as some local function of its geometry.

Comment: Nice example, thanks @mmesser314.

Answer (score 1):

For a conducting sphere of radius $r$ and surface charge density $\sigma$ has a potential $V=\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{\sigma 4\pi r^2}{r}= \dfrac{1}{\epsilon_0}(\sigma \,r)$.

Thus if the potential is constant, $\sigma \propto \dfrac 1r$.

From this result you can imagine the surface of a conductor being made up of many small “spherical cap” elements each at the same potential but with different radii and charge densities inversely proportional to the radii.

Comment: Excellent point Farcher. This is certainly what people mean when they say that charge density is related to the conductor's geometry. Given two conducting spheres at some voltage $V$, the smaller of the two will have the greater charge density.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this. At least to me, it's not so clear how principle of superposition works here: I can't just "add" little charged spheres, without prescribing that the net charge is zero inside the medium (and it seems to me that we would need to to so, since the charged surfaces of the sphere lies in the inner part of the body)

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation on the niveau of school just take two touching spheres of different radii and the same potential .

Comment: If the spheres are touching, i.e. in constant contact, then the charge density will have no dependence on the geometry.